# How to position 'content' at the end of line of a p element?

Tags: css

I want have a ■ unicode character at the end of line of some of my paragraphs. However, using :after I only get it to appear right after the paragraph in question:

```css
.end:after {
  content: "■";
}
```

```html
<p class="end"> Hello World, Lorem Ipsum msan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie </p>
```

I tried setting `text-align: right` on the pseudo-class, but it didn't seem to work.

Has someone else managed to do this?

Comment: you mean at the end of each line? you are probably looking for `float;right`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can float the `::after` pseudo element to the right:

```css
.end {
  clear: both;
}

.end:after {
  float: right;
  content: "■";
}
```

```html
<p class="end"> Hello World, Lorem Ipsum msan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet
  dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you want to place that Unicode in the place of `full stop`. For that you can wrap it inside `span` element

```css
.end:after {
   content: "■";
}
```

```html
<p> Hello World, Lorem Ipsum msan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi <span class="end"></span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat <span class="end"></span> Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie <span class="end"></span></p>
```